# Why is the SOAP XML attribute not being set?

Tags: xml, perl, soap

When creating SOAP with [`SOAP::Lite`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/SOAP-Lite)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use 5.006;
use strict;
use warnings;
use SOAP::Lite +trace => [ 'debug' ];

my $req1 = SOAP::Lite->new(
    readable => 1,
    autotype => 0,
    proxy    => 'https://ics2wstest.ic3.com/commerce/1.x/transactionProcessor',
);

# req1 does not generate the XML attribute <item id="0"> it just generates
# <item>
$req1->requestMessage(
    \SOAP::Data->new(
        name => 'item',
        attr => { id => '0' },
        value => \SOAP::Data->new(
            name => 'foo',
            value => 1,
        ),
     ),
);
```

I get this XML *(note: well this is the important part)*

```
<item>
  <foo>1</foo>
</item>
```

I do not understand why I am not getting this XML

```
<item id="0">
   <foo>1</foo>
</item>
```

can anyone tell me how to get the attribute to be generated?

*note: this near identical (instead of naming the attribute `id` it's named `foo`)  code works. so I think this may be a [bug](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=70329)*

```
$req->requestMessage(
    \SOAP::Data->new(
        name => 'item',
        attr => { foo => '0' },
        value => \SOAP::Data->new(
            name => 'foo',
            value => 1,
        ),
     ),
);
```

Comment: I think this may be an obscure bug, as if I change `id` to `foo` then it's generated... it only appears to happen if attr name is `id` and there are subelements in item.

Comment: Maybe setting the "id" attribute is handled differently from arbitrary attributes?

Comment: it could be... but if it is I'd like to know how to do it... I haven't seen anything documented to that effect. (though maybe I missed it)

Comment: XML::Simple handles `id` specially by virtue of being one of the default values for `KeyAttr` (along with `name` and `key`). Does SOAP::Lite perhaps use XML::Simple?

Comment: fyi, I've encountered many problems with SOAP::Lite. I won't be using it again.

Comment: @ikegami I discovered [`XML::Compile::SOAP`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Compile-SOAP/lib/XML/Compile/SOAP.pod) after posting this, I'm going to play with it tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**update:** [Fixed in 0.714](https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=70329)

It's conflicting with something SOAP::Lite or SOAP uses

```
sub xmlize {
    my $self = shift;
    my($name, $attrs, $values, $id) = @{+shift};
    $attrs ||= {};

    local $self->{_level} = $self->{_level} + 1;
    return $self->tag($name, $attrs)
        unless defined $values;
    return $self->tag($name, $attrs, $values)
        unless UNIVERSAL::isa($values => 'ARRAY');
    return $self->tag($name, {%$attrs, href => '#'.$self->multiref_anchor($id)})
        if $self->is_href($id, delete($attrs->{_id}));
    return $self->tag($name,
        {
            %$attrs, id => $self->multiref_anchor($id)      <-------- Clobbers your id
        },
        map {$self->xmlize($_)} @$values
    );
}
```

I think that's where your id gets lost. And was the section of code changed in 0.714

Answer (score 0):

Can you try putting quotes around `id`? Maybe that'll work.

Comment: I have in an iteration not shown, it doesn't work, besides the `=>` fat comma operator quotes words before it.